# Is Bernard Lowe in a simulation too?

Tags: westworld-2016

*Westworld* is now at a position that it is hard to tell simulation from reality. In the 2nd episode of Season 3 we see

> Maeve understanding she's living in a simulation. And she tries to get out of the simulation. And Bernard Lowe also comes to park four.

Now is it possible that Bernard Lowe is also in a simulation?

> Also it was a plot point that the computation power of the simulations isn't that high.

So does this rule out the possibility that Bernard Lowe is in a simulation, because,

> he was travelling through huge landscapes.